# Fade in right another page after loader

Tags: html, css

I am working on a piece of my personal website and what I want to do is a simple animation where the second div fades in right after the first div has loaded

Here is the code:

```
  <!-- BEGIN: PRELOADER -->
<div id="loader" class="center">
  <div class="loader animate fadeInUp one">
    <img src="img/LOGO-1.png" alt="loader" id="logo-1"/>
  </div>
      <!-- END: PRELOADER -->
  <div class="container" >
        <img src="./img/LOGO-2.png" alt="comingsoon" class="logo__img" />
</div>
    </div>``
```

Comment: Do you mean the second div fades in right after the `img` in first div has loaded?

Comment: Yes the first div has a fade in up animation when it loads which i have already done the problem is transitioning from that div using a fadein right animation after that

Comment: you can use `animation-delay` on the second div. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: are you sure i dont need a javascript function / because the first div has a fade in up animation which loads in a picture

Comment: you can `onload` event if the images' size are big. if the images are light weight, you don't need javascript.